# Is there a way to get Month to Date and Last month in Salesforce Reports

Tags: reporting

I have a custom Salesforce Object and I am trying to create a report in Salesforce. I am able to pull the Cols from the custom object onto the report and group by Col A and Col B.

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| Col A | Col B | Measure A |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|   A   |   a   |     50    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|       |   b   |     50    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|       |   c   |     50    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|   B   |   a   |     70    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|       |   b   |     70    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

But I want to be able to apply time related grouping on Measure A like Month to Date(MTD) , LastMonth and Last2Months . Is there a way to achieve that ? . It looks like the only available aggregation options are SUM, AVG, MIN/MAX and unique.

```
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
| Col A | Col B | MTD | LastMonth | Last2Months |
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|   A   |   a   |  50 |    100    |     200     |
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|       |   b   |  50 |    100    |     200     |
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|       |   c   |  50 |    100    |     200     |
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|   B   |   a   |  70 |    200    |     400     |
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|       |   b   |  70 |    200    |     400     |
+-------+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
```